# Multiple definition of static class variable

Tags: c++, bison, lex

I'm doing an assignment on compiler. So I have three files. A `SymbolInfo.h` file, a `parser.y` file and a `lex.l` file.

`SymbolInfo.h` file:

```
<include files....>

using namespace std;

#ifndef SYMBOLINFO_H_
#define SYMBOLINFO_H_

<more code...>

class SymbolTable{
    static int id;
    int bucket;
    ScopeTable* parentScope;

    <constructors and methods....>
}

#endif /* SYMBOLINFO_H_ */
```

I need to initialize the static variable `id`. So I first tried to initialize it in the `.h` file:

```
int SymbolTable::id = 0;
#endif /* SYMBOLINFO_H_ */
```

Then when I tried to compile it but it gives the following compilation error:

```
l.o:(.bss+0x28): multiple definition of `SymbolTable::id'
y.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
l.o:(.bss+0x30): multiple definition of `id'
y.o:(.bss+0x430): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
./script.sh: line 14: ./a.out: No such file or directory
```

So I removed the initialization from the `.h` file and moved them to `.l` and `.y` file.

The `.y` file:

```
%{

<some include files>
#include "SymbolInfo.h"

int SymbolTable::id = 0;

#define YYSTYPE SymbolInfo*

using namespace std;

int yyparse(void);
int yylex(void);

extern FILE *yyin;
extern int line_count;

FILE *fp;
ofstream logout,errorout;

const int bucketSize = 10;
SymbolTable symbolTable(bucketSize); 

%}
```

And the `.l` file:

```
%{

<some include files...>
#include "SymbolInfo.h"
int SymbolTable::id = 0;
#include "y.tab.h"

using namespace std;

int line_count = 1;
int TOTAL_ERROR = 0;

extern SymbolTable symbolTable;
extern FILE *yyin;
extern YYSTYPE yylval;
extern ofstream logout,errorout;

......
%}
```

But it still gives the same error and I'm not understanding why. Sorry for the long post, but any help would be appreciated.

`script.sh` file for compilation commands:

```
bison -d -y -v parser.y
g++ -std=c++11 -w -c -o y.o y.tab.c
flex "Lexical Analyzer".l
g++ -std=c++11 -w -c -o l.o lex.yy.c
g++ -std=c++11 -o a.out y.o l.o -lfl -ly
./a.out
```

**Link to full code:**

[Flex file](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2HyTygq5wv/)

[Bison file](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nt9rQmz85X/)

[SymbolTable](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Y8McwqvjKz/)

Comment: You need to put the initialization line in *exactly one* file. I'm not sure how .l and .y files are used so I can't give you a proper answer.

Comment: From what you posted, it seems your header *may* be missing include guards. Edit: followed the link; there *are* guards, but why are they below the includes? Seems an odd thing to do at the very least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look, you will see how both the `.y` and `.l` file *work together*. You will see how variables defined in one are marked as `extern` in the other and vice versa. This is because both output `.c` files. If they both include the static variable definition and then are compiled and linked, you get the "multiple definition" error.

To fix this, put the initialization in *only one* of the two files.

Comment: Thank you. It solved the problem! I should've been more careful about it.